# Null coming in final object

Tags: javascript, json

I am aggregating json object orderData if they have same order_id .In the final object ordernewdata null is coming at second index in it.is a empty object being pushed in the new array.What is that I am missing?

```
var ordersData={
  "orders":[
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 294,
      "amount": 500,
      "discount": 100,
      "created_at": "2016-11-07T07:36:46.000Z",
      "item_name": "Veg Manchurian Dry",
      "item_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 294,
      "amount": 500,
      "discount": 100,
      "created_at": "2016-11-07T07:36:46.000Z",
      "item_name": "Veg Chopsuey",
      "item_id": 2
    },
      {
      "order_id": 2,
      "user_id": 294,
      "amount": 500,
      "discount": 100,
      "created_at": "2016-11-07T07:38:42.000Z",
      "item_name": "Veg Chopsuey",
      "item_id": 2
    },


  ]
}

  var ordersnewdata ={
    "orders":[
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "amount": 1,
      "discount": 1,
      "created_at": "",
      "items":[]
    }
    ]
  };


      var i=0;  
     for(k=i+1;k<ordersData.orders.length;k++){

        if(ordersData.orders[i].order_id==ordersData.orders[k].order_id){
          var item_name = ordersData.orders[k].item_name;
          var item_id   = ordersData.orders[k].item_id;
          var obj       = {item_name:item_name,item_id:item_id};
          ordersnewdata.orders[i].items.push(obj);                
       }

     else{

      var orders={
        order_id    : ordersData.orders[k].order_id,
        user_id     : ordersData.orders[k].user_id,
        amount      : ordersData.orders[k].amount_id,
        discount    : ordersData.orders[k].discount_id,
        created_at  : ordersData.orders[k].created_at,
        items       : {item_name:ordersData.orders[k].item_name,item_id:ordersData.orders[k].item_id},
      };    
      ordersnewdata.orders[k]=orders;
     }

   }


console.log(JSON.stringify(ordersnewdata));
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/b7t3r4ae/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loop,

When **k = 1**, it goes inside the if-statement. When **k = 2**, it goes inside the *else* branch, in other words, `ordersnewdata.orders[2] = orders` for your situation. So we just forgot to evaluate `ordersnewdata.orders[1]`. That's the reason why there will be `null` in `ordernewdata.orders`.

To prevent adding `null`, you can use `ordersnewdata.orders.push(orders)` to insert new order.